# Tomcat 8 DIGEST Authentication constantly asks for password

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

I have a web application written in java and I want to protect everything that is inside admin folder which is inside WebContet folder. The issue is that the server constantly asks for username and password. My web.xml is:

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>Admin Constraint</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/admin/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>administration</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
    <realm-name>AdministrationArea</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

My users xml file is

```
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="administration"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="administration,tomcat"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
```

And my server xml file is :

```
<Context path="/admin" docBase="admin"><Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm"resourceName="AdministrationArea"digest="MD5"/></Context>
```

I am new to this. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your Tomcat configuration, but just the way HTTP authentication works. The server will ask your browser to verify username and password on every request, which is why most browser will save username and password for at least a short while.

If you want to make your webapp secure you should think about adding your own security to it, including sessions and cookies. How to do that depends on your specific configuration and the frameworks you're using, so I can't really help you more with that.

Comment: I have already added sessions and cookies. I just want to protect admin area with digest authentication. Why tomcat asks constantly for password??

Comment: Because you configured it in such a way. HTTP Digest authentication requires the username and password to be sent with every request, so either your browser saves them for a while or you get asked for every request. You should probably just not be using HTTP Digest authentication and instead just use your system of sessions and cookies to verify a password and then set a cookie like "admin" and then check for that in your code.

Comment: I see. So after the request is performed to the servlet in the admin area, the servlet should respond with a session cookie or something similar right?

Comment: Yes. Instead of using HTTP Digest Authentication you should use your own password verification that just sets a cookie or a session variable. Maybe a tutorial like [this](http://www.journaldev.com/1907/java-servlet-session-management-tutorial-with-examples-of-cookies-httpsession-and-url-rewriting) will help